# Static assert usage with template functions and classes for specialization?

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, specialization, static-assert

I've been using `static_assert` and template class (functor) to implement some metaprogrmamming functionality. e.g.

```
struct triangle { unsigned int a_, b_, c_; }
struct triangleMesh { std::vector<triangle> triangles_; }

struct point2D { double x_, y_; };
struct point2D { double x_, y_, z_; };

struct mesh2D : public triangleMesh { std::vector<point2D> points_; }
struct mesh3D : public triangleMesh { std::vector<point3D> points_; }

// Generate triangle mesh implementation...
template <class R, V>
class GenerateTrianglesImpl
{

    // Enforce certain combinations of types...
    std::static_assert(std::is_base_of<point3D, V>::value && std::is_base_of<mesh3D, R>::value ||
        std::is_base_of<point2D, V>::value && std::is_base_of<mesh2D, R>::value, 
        "GenerateTrianglesImpl return (R) and value (V) must be same dimension");

public:
    std::shared_ptr<R> operator()(const std::vector<V>& points)
    {
        if (vs.size() % 3 != 0)
            std::runtime_error("GenerateTrianglesImpl points input is not a multiple of 3");

        // populate the mesh and return it...

        return std::shared_ptr<R>(...);
    }

};
```

In this example I can ensure that any callers of my template class provide `R` (return type) and `V` (value type) types which are compatible with each other and can stop other developers using this template class with nonsensical `R` and `V` types i.e.

```
GenerateTrianglesImpl<mesh2D, point3D>()(some3DPoints);     // static_assert triggers to prevent this instantiation...
```

I opted for this as I feel it is slightly more elegant by enforcing type usage (or combination of) via `static_assert` rather than specialization and also I could (potentially) refactor larger routines into private methods within the template class rather than pollute a parent namespace with helper/ancillary functions for the template class.

*Questions...*

Would this be classified as template specialization? It's not providing different implementations for the different types, however it is enforcing usage with certain types (and combinations of certain types)?

Is this a good way to enforce usage to specific combinations of types within templates instead of specialization enforcing these various combinations (more coding if using specialization being the obvious one for me at the moment)?

Are there advantages and/or disadvantages to having a template function over a template class with this behavior (`static_assert` as opposed to specialization)?

Comment: If this was a C++ question, I'd say look at Concepts (in C++20).

Comment: @QuentinUK Thanks, and yes, forgot to add that tag.

Comment: here's an example of Concept and Constraints for the above code https://godbolt.org/z/__hWG9 (I've only just learn about these myself so I don't know if it's the best way.) (also I don't think people are answering because this is an "opinion based question" and any answers would get downvotes.)

Comment: @QuentinUK Thanks for your help. Yes probably won't get an answer, however that looks intersting and along the lines of what I would like to be doing I think. Will check it out. :)